# Calling methods from base class with Linq2Sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Here are the list of methods for selecting users by different parameters.
For example I want to call `GetUsers(string email, bool isActive)`. 
Will Linq2Sql selects a list of all active users with `GetUsers(bool isActive)` and pass this list to `GetUsers(int userId, bool isActive)`? Or I'll have only one call to a database in `GetUsers(string email, bool isActive)`?

```
    internal IQueryable<User> GetUsers(bool isActive)
    {
        IQueryable<User> users = Context.Users;

        if (isActive)
            users = users.Active();

        return users;
    }

    internal IQueryable<User> GetUsers(int userId, bool isActive)
    {
        return this.GetUsers(isActive).Where(item => item.Id == userId);
    }

    internal IQueryable<User> GetUsers(string email, bool isActive)
    {
        return this.GetUsers(isActive).Where(item => item.Email.Equals(email, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
```

Comment: "Or I'll have only one call to a database in". Try it out with SQL Profiler to see how many SQL queries are sent to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using IQueryable defers the SQL execution and chains the select statement, so there will only be one request.

If you had used IList or anything other that IQueryable this would not be the case however.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on the query provider. In your case it is Linq2Sql which is pretty optimized. The other `GetUsers` overloads will add the criteria to the expression. The first time you'll actually get data from the `IQueryable` instance it will be translated into a SQL statement.